turn off OS verification on a Lenovo Chromebook Duet 5
I'm trying to setup linux on a lenovo chromebook duet 5, but I'm having trouble booting to a linux USB. I think that the problem is that I need to turn off OS verification, but I'm not sure how. Here's what I've done so far:
I've mostly been working from these tutorials
https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Chromebook
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Chrome_OS_devices
https://www.wikihow.com/Enable-USB-Booting-on-Chromebook
With this help, I've set the device to developer mode and enabled booting from USB. The tutorials indicate that when the devices switches to developer mode, it should ask if I'd like to turn off OS verification, but weirdly I never hit that prompt. The recovery/developer menu presents a "boot from external disk" option, but when I select that I get "No valid image detected. Make sure your external disk has a valid Chrome OS image." I've tried multiple USB devices, but with the same result.
In the cross shell in developer mode, which I can access with ctrl+alt+refresh/F2 during startup, I'm prompted to use this command to boot from self-signed external images
enable_dev_boot_usb
Running this command produces a message that says that I can now boot from a self-signed image. I'm actually not sure what that means, but I'm still not able to boot from a linux USB.
Two of the tutorials suggest that it might be necessary to flash the firmware, but they both suggest MrChromebox's Firmware Utility Script, doesn't support ARM, and this device is ARM. The other option suggested in the Arch tutorial is coreboot, but that doesn't appear to support ARM either.
I've also searched for documentation from Lenovo on how to disable OS verification, but without success. If anyone has any clue, I'd be grateful!
